# gb4e & pst-jtree: Invalid item error when using "^" inside a jtree in a gb4e example enclosed by braces

Tags: errors, linguistics, gb4e, pst-jtree

Pst-jtree throws an invalid item error when you attempt to draw a tree that uses the carat inside a gb4e example enclosed in braces. If you do the example without enclosing it in braces or without using the carat, it compiles.

In the MWE, the first two examples that are commented out compile correctly, but the last one doesn't.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{exe}
       %\ex\jtree\! = <left> ^ <right>.\endjtree % Works
       %\ex\jtree\! = :{}.\endjtree % Also works
        \ex[]{\jtree\! = <left> ^ <right>.\endjtree} % Doesn't work
    \end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gb4e` package allows `_` and `^` to be used outside of math mode, and this sometimes interacts badly with other packages.  The simplest solution to the problem is to issue the `\noautomath` command immediately after loading `gb4e` to turn off this feature.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{pst-jtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}
    \begin{exe}
       \ex\jtree\! = <left> ^ <right>.\endjtree % Works
       \ex\jtree\! = :{}.\endjtree % Also works
        \ex[]{\jtree\! = <left> ^ <right>.\endjtree} % Also works
    \end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]